# Permissions problem when using ruby based snap 'mdl'

Tags: permissions, ruby, apparmor, snap, markdown

Because I don't understand Ruby, but want to use the ruby based program mdl (markdownlint), I have installed it using snap.

While I can run the program, if I try and set up a customizations in a ~/.mdlrc file. I get the following error

```
 $ mdl README.md
 
 /snap/mdl/171/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mixlib-config-3.0.6/lib/mixlib/config.rb:63:in
 `read': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/mikeg/.mdlrc
 (Errno::EACCES)
         from /snap/mdl/171/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mixlib-config-3.0.6/lib/mixlib/config.rb:63:in
 `from_file'
         from /snap/mdl/171/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mdl-0.10.0/lib/mdl/cli.rb:122:in
 `run'
         from /snap/mdl/171/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mdl-0.10.0/lib/mdl.rb:16:in
 `run'
         from /snap/mdl/171/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mdl-0.10.0/bin/mdl:10:in `<top
 (required)>'
         from /snap/mdl/171/bin/mdl:23:in `load'
         from /snap/mdl/171/bin/mdl:23:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand where the permission issue comes from since

```
 $ ls -l ~/.mdlrc ~/.mdlrc.style.rb
 
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 mikeg mikeg 171 Aug 14 16:06 /home/mikeg/.mdlrc
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 mikeg mikeg   4 Aug 14 16:06 /home/mikeg/.mdlrc.style.rb
```

and

```
drwxr-xr-x 303 mikeg mikeg 65536 Aug 14 21:53 /home/mikeg
```

As a result, I can't figure out how to fix this.  Can anyone help me.

Note that I'm running Mate 18.06. SELinux is not installed, but AppArmor is active and going through my /var/log/syslog* files I get

```
syslog.7.gz:Aug 17 09:08:40 XXXX kernel: [978608.742842] audit: type=1400 audit(1597669720.954:2800): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.mdl.mdl" name="/home/mi/.mdlrc" pid=13189 comm="ruby" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Add the permissions of the parent directory to your question.

Comment: done.  It's a personal machine.

Comment: My mistake, I meant your home directory. Does `/home/mikeg` have 700 permissions? Add that to your question.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: Nope. Not even installed. ` $ getenforce
 
 Command 'getenforce' not found, but can be installed with:
 
 sudo apt install selinux-utils`

Comment: @NasirRiley I've learned that ubuntu doesn't use SELinux, but Apparmor.  Perhaps that's the cause?

Answer (score 0):

@NasirRiely's question about SELinux was helpful in identifying the root cause of the issue which is a combination of apparmor permissions and snap.  Apparently it can't read files in my home dir and installing the mdl snap `--classic` option didn't help (it was ignored for security reasons).

I started going down that rabbit hole, but decided to stop and simply install ruby and mdl using gems.  That is,

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-full
$ gem install mdl
```